# Asynchronous retrieval of WebExtension browser history visits

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm writing a small class that wraps the existing functionality of [`browser.history.search`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/history/search) in Firefox's WebExtensions API. The current API only directly searches for unique webpages as a `HistoryItem` that shows the last visit, but I need to get all visits within a given time frame.

This is done by finding all the `HistoryItem` results, then getting their associated `VisitItem` objects and combining their attributes into a result object. All of the history API search methods are asynchronous, so I tried to speed the process up by getting the visits of each history item without waiting for the results of the previous, and returning once all the calls were completed.

The code will work given a properly given a properly setup Firefox Addon. However, I'm not very familiar with promises or asynchronous programming, so I'm not sure if I've structured this in the most appropriate way.

I appreciate any feedback.

```
    function HistoryVisitFinder() {

      /* Largest value of `maxResults` property that is accepted by the `query`
      argument of browser.history.search().
      This is a temporary workaround to the lack of a method for streaming large
      number of results. */
      const maxResultsCeiling = Math.pow(2, 52);
      const msPerDay = 86400000;

      function getLocalDateMsBounds(date) {
        /* Get the start and end time in milliseconds-since-epoch for the local day
        of `date` */

        const localDateStart = (new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(),
          date.getDate())).getTime();
        return [localDateStart, localDateStart + msPerDay - 1];
      }

      this.searchVisits = async function(text, startTime, endTime) {
        /*
        Find objects representing webpage history visits whose domain and/or url
        contain `text` and whose visit times are within the inclusive range of
        `startTime` to `endTime`.

        Returns an array of objects with the associated HistoryItem and VisitItem
        attributes:
          { url, title, id, referringVisitId, transition, visitTime }
        */
        const results = [];
        const query = {
          text,
          startTime,
          endTime,
          maxResults: maxResultsCeiling
        };
        const historyItemArray = await browser.history.search(query);
        const expected = [];

        const filterVisitsCallback = function(visit) {
          return visit.visitTime <= endTime && visit.visitTime >= startTime;
        }

        /* Store the visits of each HistoryItem that fall between `startTime` and
        `endTime` */
        for (let historyItem of historyItemArray) {
          const url = historyItem.url;
          const title = historyItem.title;

          const mapVisitsCallback = function(visit) {
            return {
              url,
              title,
              id: visit.visitId,
              referringVisitId: visit.referringVisitId,
              transition: visit.transition,
              visitTime: visit.visitTime
            }
          }

          expected.push(browser.history.getVisits({
              url
            })
            .then(visitItemArray => {
              results.push(...(
                visitItemArray
                .filter(filterVisitsCallback)
                .map(mapVisitsCallback)
              ))
            })
            .catch(reason => {
              console.warn('Could not get visits for HistoryItem', historyItem,
                'Reason:', reason);
            })
          );
        }

        return await Promise.all(expected).then(() => {
          /* Sort results in reverse chronological order */
          results.sort((a, b) => b.visitTime - a.visitTime);
          return results;
        });
      }

      this.getVisitsOnDate = async function(text, date) {
        /*
        Find objects representing webpage history visits whose domain and/or url
        contain `text` and whose visit times are on the same day as `date`.

        Returns an array of objects with the associated HistoryItem and VisitItem
        attributes:
          { url, title, id, referringVisitId, transition, visitTime }
        */
        const [startTime, endTime] = getLocalDateMsBounds(date);

        return await this.searchVisits(text, startTime, endTime);

      }
    }
```

Run using:

```
    const historyFinder = new HistoryVisitFinder();
    historyFinder.getVisitsOnDate('', new Date()).then(console.log);
```

Comment: (I expect code in code blocks, not hidden snippets - that may just be me. My comments were appropriate for code reachable via external hyperlinks.) Welcome to Code Review!

Comment: I put it in the snippet so that the block doesn't instantly push the rest of the question off-screen. If that's unacceptable I can move it to a regular block, but that's less readable in my opinion. What do you mean by "reachable via external hyperlinks"? Thanks for your feedback.